# HOW TO USE THE CLASS OF "openPerspectiveMenu" IN A CLASS?

Tags: eclipse

I want to develope plug-ins in eclipse,the function of the plug-ins is when right-click menu the button opens a perspective.I find the class which is "openPerspectiveMenu" has not been used,please tell me the alternative.
  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The way to open a perspective programmatically is to call:

```
IWorkbench.showPerspective(String perspectiveId,
                               IWorkbenchWindow window)
                               throws WorkbenchException
```

[Javadoc here.](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbench.html)

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_show_a_given_perspective%3F for details.